# Linear combinations of Zygote.Grads

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am building and training a neural network model with Flux, and I am wondering if there is a way to take linear combinations of `Zygote.Grads` types.

Here is a minimalistic example. This is how it is typically done:

```
m = hcat(2.0); b = hcat(-1.0);  # random 1 x 1 matrices

f(x) = m*x .+ b
ps = Flux.params(m, b)  # parameters to be adjusted

inputs = [0.3 1.5]  # random 1 x 2 matrix

loss(x) = sum( f(x).^2 )

gs = Flux.gradient(() -> loss(inputs), ps)  # the typical way
@show gs[m], gs[b]  # 5.76, 3.2
```

But I want to do the same calculation by computing gradients at a deeper level, and then assembling it at the end. For example:

```
input1 = hcat(inputs[1, 1]); input2 = hcat(inputs[1, 2]);  # turn each input into a 1 x 1 matrix

grad1 = Flux.gradient(() -> f(input1)[1], ps)  # df/dp using input1 (where p is m or b)
grad2 = Flux.gradient(() -> f(input2)[1], ps)  # df/dp using input2 (where p is m or b)

predicted1 = f(input1)[1]
predicted2 = f(input2)[1]

myGrad_m = (2 * predicted1 * grad1[m]) + (2 * predicted2 * grad2[m])  # 5.76
myGrad_b = (2 * predicted1 * grad1[b]) + (2 * predicted2 * grad2[b])  # 3.2
```

Above, I used the chain rule and linearity of the derivative to decompose the gradient of the `loss()` function:

```
d(loss)/dp = d( sum(f^2) ) / dp = sum( d(f^2)/dp ) = sum( 2*f * df/dp )
```

Then, I calculated `df/dp` using `Zygote.gradient`, and then combined the results at the end.

But notice that I had to combine `m` and `b` separately. This was fine because there were only 2 parameters.

However, if there were a 1000 parameters, I would want to do something like this, which is a linear combination of the `Zygote.Grads`:

```
myGrad = (2 * predicted1 * grad1) + (2 * predicted2 * grad2)
```

But, I get an error saying that the `+` and `*` operators are not defined for these types. How can I get this shortcut to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn each `*`/`+` into `.*`/`.+` (i.e. use broadcasting) or you can use `map` to apply a function to multiple `Grads` at once. This is described in the Zygote docs [here](https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/latest/utils/#Working-with-Grads-1). Note that in order for this to work, all the `Grads` must share the same keys (so they must correspond to the same parameters).